# Trying to get dll from the GAC and make it work in the project

Tags: c#, dll

Probably looks like a stupid/crazy thing to do. But still, I would make my life easier if y made my project independent from 3rd party installations.

The referenced assembly I need is `Microsoft.Research.Science.Data`. See ["SDS: Scientific DataSet library and tools"](https://sds.codeplex.com/) for more info.

So I download the installer and run it. Now the assembly appears in my c# project, and I can reference it. Good. I make the code work and now I am able to read NetCDF files.

Now I want to try to make the code independent from this 3rd party installer, because my project is used and debugged by several users / machines / etc. And it is going to be easier for me to maintain if I am able to get all the portable dll's and put them into my \lib of the project.

Step one: I get the dll's from the assembly.

```
11/06/2010  19:33            52.224 Microsoft.Research.Science.Data.CSV.dll
11/06/2010  19:33            46.572 Microsoft.Research.Science.Data.CSV.XML
11/06/2010  19:33           196.096 Microsoft.Research.Science.Data.dll
11/06/2010  19:33            18.944 Microsoft.Research.Science.Data.Imperative.dll
11/06/2010  19:33            60.635 Microsoft.Research.Science.Data.Imperative.XML
11/06/2010  19:33            11.776 Microsoft.Research.Science.Data.Memory.dll
11/06/2010  19:33             9.388 Microsoft.Research.Science.Data.Memory.XML
11/06/2010  19:33           528.210 Microsoft.Research.Science.Data.XML
```

I import them into the project. No compilation errors... good. I run the code to test it, try to load the .nc file into the DataSet structure and...

```
"Failed to create DataSet instance from uri C:\testFile.nc: Extension .nc is not registered in the factory"
```

OK, I dig deeper to find where this netcdf dll might hide. I see that the GAC has it referenced (one in GAC_32, the other in GAC_64). I get both dll's. I import them into the project and...

```
A reference to the "....dll" could not be added.Please make sure that the file is accessible and that it is a valid assembly or COM component.
```

Fair enough since I didn't know what the hell I was doing at this point, I was just trying what seemed feasible.

I try putting the dll in the binary directory during the execution. Same exception.

So now I am completely stuck, but at the same time I feel like I am not that far away from making it work. Any ideas? Or is it like looking for a needle in a haystack?

Comment: Backing up to the initial case where you've only run the installer: when you build your project, do you see the required dlls in your build output dir? If so, can't you simply distribute the dlls with your project?

Comment: Also, have you tried "Copy Local" as per here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/t1zz5y8c(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Documentation is actually pretty good, it is not very common for a library to describe how it installs itself.  Quote: "Four data providers are registered in the computer’s Machine.config configuration file".  A *not registered in the factory* exception sure makes it sound like that didn't happen.  Maybe you shouldn't try so hard to avoid the known-good installer.  Just make it a prerequisite.

Comment: @0x1mason I checked the "copy local" option and it only copies the main dll (which is `Microsoft.Research.Science.Data.dll`), so apparently the "secondary" libraries called by this "main" library are not copied in the binary folder. That is to say: I still don't have the whole package to make it work independently.

Comment: @HansPassant In retrospective I think you are right: documentation is not that bad... I mean, the project is great, don't take me wrong. It is just that troubleshooting is hard, since it is not a widely used project. But it does something no other c# library that I know is able to do: read NetCDF. Anyway if the reference depends on the `Machine.config` configuration file maybe it is not realistic for me to try to make it portable. I felt I was pretty close though, because I think I reached all dll's there were needed for the project and just had to combine them correctly. I had to ask.

Comment: Nuget is another possibility maybe?: https://www.nuget.org/packages/SDSLite/

Comment: @0x1mason Well his is a great hint! Of course nothing is that easy in programming, because now I have to deal with this: `Successfully installed 'SDSLite 1.4' to Project // Added file 'app.config'. // Install failed. Rolling back...`. Maybe it doesn't like that it is .net 4.5 ... I'll keep digging.

Comment: @0x1mason I am sorry, was in a rush before and I couldn't test it properly. Turns out that the `app.config` was linked in another project under the same solution and Nuget didn't like that. Solved that problem, I could properly install the SDSLite Nuget package. But when I test it with the same code, opening the .nc file I get `Failed to create DataSet instance from uri C:\myNetCdfFile.nc: The type initializer for 'NetCDFInterop.NetCDFDynamic' threw an exception.`. I still hope I can fix it because the Nuget says `This is a cross platform library for manipulating netCDF, CSV and TSV files.`.

Comment: So... it turns out that all my previous work was not in vain after all. The inner error was `{"netcdf.dll not found in current directory nor on system path nor in ProgramFilesX86":Nothing}`, so I go find the dll's that I took from the GAC and it turns out that it work! The nuget package was a great hint from @0x1mason , I wish I could upvote you more.

Comment: Glad you got it working.